# In Logic Pro X is there a way to split the output of an audio track to two tracks (live)?

Tags: mixing, logic-pro

Is there a way to route the output of a track to 2 or more other tracks?  Busses would work in theory but I'd rather the outputs be to tracks in the main window.  What I'm after is kind of the inverse of a track folder...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your aim is to simply be able to see the buss/aux tracks in the "Tracks area"...

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13024?viewlocale=en_US

...then you can make the "busses"/"auxes" visible in the "Tracks area". This can be done by going in the "Mixer" window and Ctrl clicking anywhere in the channel strip you want to have shown in the "Tracks area". Then select "Create Track". You will now have a "buss"/"aux" track showing in the "Tracks area".

However, if your desire is to just create two physical outputs from Logic Pro X... And you are using an Apogee Symphony I/O unit... You can mirror the output of one track in the "Track area" by using Apogee's Maestro routing software. This will allow you to direct, say, Logic Pro X software "output 1-2" via hardware "output 1-2" and "output 3-4" simultaneously.

-

Failing that...

If your sound source is input via an external live input i.e. a microphone, which you want to be able to affect differently on two channels... Then simply created two "audio tracks" with the same input source e.g. if using an Apogee Duet with mic coming in via "input 1", select the input of each "audio track" to be "input 1". Make sure the "Input Monitoring" buttons is enabled on each track to be able to hear the two channels without the need to record or playback.

If you're looking to playback an audio file without using the buss channels... Why not simply create two "audio tracks" and copy the same audio file onto both tracks.

Or... If you're using a "software instrument", then you could do something similar to the above i.e. create two new "software instrument" channels with same "instrument plugin" and make sure the MIDI regions are copied into the same postions on each track.

You might also be able to achieve this via "Track Stacks" in Logic Pro X too:

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12948?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: It was for a software instrument which I wanted to treat in two different ways to thicken it up. I could have two instance but I just thought it seemed inefficient and that there might be a way to manual wire up its output to the input of two audio tracks? Environment maybe??  Good tip about the Aux/Busses in tracks view. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer...

1. In the mixer, create two Aux tracks (Ctrl+N in Mac)
2. Change their input to an unused bus, say Bus 10
3. Go to your track you wish to split, and make it's output Bus 10
4. (Make sure the volume is turned up on the new Aux tracks)

Voila!